# Why does pushing a derefernced pointer to Stack output null here?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, stack

This program is meant to split a string I would input, for example **2 + 3** then it would detect that it's an infix expression and then convert to postfix for example **2 3 +** (The delimiter for strtok is an empty space like so: **" "**).

My issue thus far is that whenever I try to push an element into my operator stack **(opStack)** and then print out the corresponding element it was supposed to be stored in, the program outputs that it is null.

In other words my push function is not working correctly, I suspect that it has something to do with me trying to pass the **(&token)** to the function and then dereferencing it in **(push)**.

Kind of stumped at this point so any assistance would be much obliged.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char opStack[5]; // Global operator stack
char operandStack[6]; // Global operand stack
char outputArray[25]={'\0'}; // Output array
int top = -1;
int endOfArray = 25;

int determine_notation(char input[25], int length);
void push(char* operator2store);
void pop(char operator2store);
void strSplit(char input[25]);

int main(void)
{
   char expression[25] = {'\0'}; // Initializing character array to NULL
   int notation;
   int expr_length, i;
   expression[25] = '\0';
   printf("Please enter your expression to detect and convert it's notation: ");
   fgets(expression, 25, stdin);

   expr_length = strlen(expression); // Determining size of array input until the NULL terminator
   notation = determine_notation(expression, expr_length);
   strSplit(expression);
}

void push(char* operator2store)
{
    opStack[top++] = *operator2store;
    printf("top value is: %d\n", top);
    printf("Element in opStack[0] is: %s\n", opStack[top]);
    if(top == -1)
    {
    printf("Stack is empty\n");
    }
}
void strSplit(char input[25])
{
   const char s[2]= " ";
   char *token;
   token = strtok(input, s);

   while(token != '\0')
   {

      if(*token == '+' || *token == '-' || *token == '*' || *token == '/' ||  *token == '^' || *token == ')') // If the token is an operator it will be pushed to stack
      {
         printf("operator is: %s\n", token);
         push(&token);
      }
      else
      {
         printf("numbers are: %s\n", token);
      }
      token = strtok('\0', s);
   }
}
```

Comment: OT: You are aware that `strSplit(char input[25])` in fact is equivalent to `strSplit(char * input)`?

Comment: `opStack[top++] = *operator2store;` : at first time `top` is `-1`.  `opStack[-1] = ...` is invalid. `expression[25] = '\0';` write to out of bounds. (unnecessary, All elements already initialized to 0. )

Comment: Nice catch, that expression [25] I didn't see, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- Your `push(char* operator2store)` takes a `char*`as its argument
- Your `token` is a `char *` .

When you pass in `&token` , you pass inn a `char**` , which should give you a compiler warning. `token` is already the correct type, you just need to do:

```
 push(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, it finally worked.

> I had to pass my token this way like nos said **push(token)** and then I also needed to increment my **top** global variable BEFORE I used it to indicate the top of my LIFO stack.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack algorithm is broken.

```
opStack[top++] = *operator2store;            // << Store value at index n
printf("top value is: %d\n", top);           // << print n+1
printf("Element in opStack[0] is: %s\n", opStack[top]); // << print element at index n+1
if(top == -1)  
// While pushing on the stack, how could it get emtpy? 
// Checking for stack full woule be better.
```

Aside from starting before the actual array (`int top=-1;`) you mess up your stack pointer.